# 6017 Bad format or missing mandatory value for field Text in section MESSAGE

Tags: groove

I am trying to use for OTP but some how its showing me Error

```
def msg = """Subject=Demo
[MSISDN]
List=+918888888888
[MESSAGE]
Text=This is a text message.
[SETUP]
MobileNotification= YES
[END]"""
```

but its showing me Error..

```
INFO HttpResponse[statusLine=400:Bad   Request,contentType=text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1,contentEncoding=null,contentLength=182,content=<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY> br
6017 Bad format or missing mandatory value for field Text in section MESSAGE.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Please give solution if anything you have..Waiting for reply..